# PHP Long string. Output it all

Tags: php, string, long-integer

So I got a really long string, made by a calculator.

```
$string='483451102828322427131269442894636268716773727170';
$result=(8902543901+$string)*($string/93.189)/($string)+55643907015.57895461;
echo $result;
```

This outputs 5.1878558931668E+45

So now my question is. How can I output the whole string, without that nasty E+45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP on a 64 bit machine can only accurately calculate number up until 9223372036854775807. As soon as you calculate with numbers higher than that, php will switch to floats which may loose some of it's precision, especially when you use divisions.

There's an extension for php that will allow you to make calculations based on string, called [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Example:

```
$string = '483451102828322427131269442894636268716773727170';
$result = bcadd($string, 8902543901);
echo $result;
```

[bcadd()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) is for additions, [bcdiv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php) for divisions and [bcmul()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) for multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

You can't print exact value because you are using calculation, so this $string becomes a number (float in this case) and all numbers have limited precision.

If you want to do operations on big numbers you should use [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.bc.php)

However if you want to display it without scientific notation you can do it using:

```
echo sprintf("%f",$result);
```

or

```
echo sprintf("%.0f",$result);
```

if you want to omit decimal part